# How to select just the third or fourth row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a little bit of trouble figuring out a way to select just the third or fourth row in a query I am writing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of the code I came up with, this however only selects the first row.

```
Left Outer Join (select ap_attachments.ap_table_key, ap_description, ap_creation_date, ap_creation_time, ap_file_name, ap_attach_id
                     from ap_attachments
                          inner join (select Min(ap_attachment_id) ap_attach_id, ap_table_key
                                      from ap_attachments
                                      where ap_file_name like '%jpg%'
                                      group by ap_table_key) C 
                             On ap_attachments.ap_attachment_id = C.ap_attach_id) apImgThree_attach 
        On apImgTwo_attach.ap_table_key = order_link.to_order_id
```

Comment: Check out `row_number()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
select ap_attachment_id, ap_table_key,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ap_table_key ORDER BY ap_attachment_id) AS RN
from ap_attachments
where ap_file_name like '%jpg%'
```

Then you can specify which row you'd like to return using the `RN` value. This may require some adapting depending on your source data, the `DENSE_RANK()` function may be more appropriate.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY Some_Date`  then for each unique date value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the docs on lead and lag. You can also use the PARTITION clause to create the window within a specific date, for example;

```
declare @table table(
[flower] [sysname]);
insert into @table
        ([flower])
values      (N'rose'),
        (N'tulip'),
        (N'chamomile'),
        (N'lily');
select [flower] from   @table order  by [flower];
select [flower]
   , lag ([flower]
          , 1
          , 0)
       over (
         order by [flower] desc) as [previous_flower]
   , lead ([flower]
           , 1
           , 0)
       over (
         order by [flower] desc) as [next_flower]
from   @table;
```